# Verificación de token con expres.js

Tags: nodejs, api, express, ecmascript-6

Estoy creando una Api. Y en un punto quiero verificar un token, el inconveniente llega cuando quiero acceder a esa propiedad desde un middlewar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Mi headers en Postman

El código del middlewar

```
export const verifyToken=(res, req, next)=>{
 console.log(req.headers['x-access-token']);
 next() }
```

con esto la el console.log me devuelve: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'x-access-token' of undefined*

El código de la ruta

```
router.get("/news:featured",verifyToken, Ctrl.news);
```

Estuve leyendo que headers no debe ser tratado como un objeto sino como una funcion osea

```
req.headers('x-access-token')
```

Pero como esperaba el console.log me devolvió: *TypeError: req.headers is not a function*

También probé con el `req.get('x-access-token')` que te dan en la documentación de express, pero el console.log me devuelve un *undefined*

Además intente con `req.header('x-access-token')` pero no me da el valor de esa propiedad si no que todo `req`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que pusiste en el orden incorrecto los parámetros req y res de la función verifyToken.

La forma correcta es:

```js
export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.headers['x-access-token']);
    next()
}
```